# Receiving error when using component={TouchableOpacity} in link tag

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-native

I am trying to create a navigation bar that has tabs that link to different pages. I have currently gotten it to work when I use

```
<Link to='/' style={styles.tabContainer}>
     <TouchableOpacity >
           <Text style={styles.tabText}>Home</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</Link>
```

However when I long press the button I get a black filling. I have found a workaround that uses

```
<Link to='/' component={TouchableOpacity} style={styles.tabContainer}>
     <Text style={styles.tabText}>Home</Text>
</Link>
```

The black filling is no longer present, but when I use this method I get the error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.defaultPrevented').

Please let me know if you need more information and thanks for any help.

Comment: Which navigation you are using ? react-router-native?

Comment: yes im using react-router-native

Comment: Try to wrap your `Link` with `TouchableOpacity `.

Comment: If I do that I get the error Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

Comment: Can you make a snack on expo?

Comment: sure give me a few minutes

Comment: I found my error. I was including 
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'; instead of import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to post the answer just in case anyone makes the same mistake that I made. 
I was including my Touchable opacity like this:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

the correct library to import touchable opacity from is

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
```

So if you do get the error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.defaultPrevented'). I would check the library that you are importing touchableOpacity from before you panick.